# Resolve promise sequentially in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have several functions and that needs to be executed sequentially,

```
function home() {
  var home = document.getElementById('home');
  html2canvas(home).then(function(canvas) {
    home.appendChild(canvas);
    var basic = canvas.toDataURL();
    var item = {};
    item["image"] = basic;
    item["width"] = 595;
    data_1.push(item);
  });
}

function options() {
  var temp_cnt = 0;
  $('.tour_options_table_data_info').each(function( index, element ) { 
   html2canvas(element).then(function(canvas) {
    element.appendChild(canvas);
    elem  = canvas.toDataURL();
    var item = {};
    item["image"] = elem;
    item["width"] = 595;
    data_1.push(item);
  }); 
 });
}

function inclusions() {
  $('.inc-main1,.inc-main2,.inc-main3').each(function( index, element ) { 
   html2canvas(element).then(function(canvas) {
    element.appendChild(canvas);
    elem  = canvas.toDataURL();
    var item = {};
    item["image"] = elem;
    item["width"] = 595;
    data_1.push(item);
  }); 
 });
}
```

`function home()` should be called first, `options()` should be call 2nd, and so on
I have `$.when()` like

```
$.when(home(),options(),inclusions()).done(function(a,b,c) {
  console.log(a,b,c);
})
```

but it doesn't call functions sequentially
Please suggest me a way here.

Comment: There's no way to do this as you intend. If data from the one request is required in the next, then you will have to perform them sequentially - ie. chain them within their callbacks.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just want to push data in `data_1` array sequentially, I mean first it should have `home()` then it should have `options()` data, is it possible without chaining their callbacks?

Comment: If you can identify each request's data in the array so that it can be run through `sort()`, then yes, otherwise no.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If I don't use prev function data into next then its possible to call it sequentially?

Comment: did you try `$.when({}).then(home).then(options).then(inclusions)` instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems all you need is to chain the Promises correctly

```
function home() {
    var home = document.getElementById('home');
    // return the promise, so you can chain it
    return html2canvas(home).then(function(canvas) {
        home.appendChild(canvas);
        var basic = canvas.toDataURL();
        var item = {};
        item["image"] = basic;
        item["width"] = 595;
        data_1.push(item);
    });
}

function options() {
    // create a promise to chain in .each
    var ret = $.when();
    $('.tour_options_table_data_info').each(function(index, element) {
        // chain the promises
        ret = ret.then(function() {
            html2canvas(element).then(function(canvas) {
                element.appendChild(canvas);
                elem = canvas.toDataURL();
                var item = {};
                item["image"] = elem;
                item["width"] = 595;
                data_1.push(item);
            });
        });
    });
    // return the last promise
    return ret;
}

function inclusions() {
    // create a promise to chain in .each
    var ret = $.when();
    $('.inc-main1,.inc-main2,.inc-main3').each(function(index, element) {
        // chain the promises
        ret = ret.then(function() {
            html2canvas(element).then(function(canvas) {
                element.appendChild(canvas);
                elem = canvas.toDataURL();
                var item = {};
                item["image"] = elem;
                item["width"] = 595;
                data_1.push(item);
            });
        });
    });
    // return the last promise
    return ret;
}
home().then(options).then(inclusions).then(() => {
    // data_1 has all the "items" in the order you need
    // i.e. home item, n * options items, m * inclusions items
});
```